How to handle NodeJS errors in TypeScript?
I'm trying to handle exceptions thrown by NodeJS using TypeScript.
For example, if I get an ECONNREFUSED exception, it's of type SystemError.
But as of now, because err is of type any, I can only do this
redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Error: ', err);
});

But I would like to narrow down the error type, similar to this:
redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
  if (err instanceof SystemError) {
    if(err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED ') {
      throw new Error('Connection refused');
    }
  }
  
  throw err;
});

But unfortunately, SystemError is not exported in Node.
I did find a discussion on GitHub from 4 years ago regarding NodeJS.ErrnoException, but seems like it was removed.
Is it currently possible in NodeJS?

Note: This is also discussed at the GitHub issue nodejs/node#46869 — Export SystemError
I needed to discriminate system errors in the type system in some past projects and didn't find any packages that did so in a way that was satisfactory, so I wrote a simple, extensible module that I've been using since then — it defines some interfaces from information in the Node.js documentation (links to source included) and type guards which use those interfaces:
system_error.ts:
import { getSystemErrorMap } from "node:util";
import { isNativeError } from "node:util/types";

/** https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/errors.html#class-systemerror */
export interface BaseSystemError<Code extends string = string> extends Error {
  /** The string error code */
  code: Code;

  /** The system-provided error number */
  errno: number;

  /** A system-provided human-readable description of the error */
  message: string;

  /** The name of the system call that triggered the error */
  syscall: string;
}

/** https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/errors.html#class-systemerror */
export interface SystemError<Code extends string = string>
  extends BaseSystemError<Code> {
  /** If present, the address to which a network connection failed */
  address?: string;

  /** If present, the file path destination when reporting a file system error */
  dest?: string;

  /** If present, extra details about the error condition */
  info?: Record<string, unknown>;

  /** If present, the file path when reporting a file system error */
  path?: string;

  /** If present, the network connection port that is not available */
  port?: number;
}

// Memo (lazily initialized):
// https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/util.html#utilgetsystemerrormap
let systemErrorMap: ReturnType<typeof getSystemErrorMap> | undefined;

type JsType =
  | "bigint"
  | "boolean"
  | "function"
  | "number"
  | "object"
  | "string"
  | "symbol"
  | "undefined";

export function isSystemError(value: unknown): value is SystemError {
  // https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/util.html#utiltypesisnativeerrorvalue
  if (!isNativeError(value)) return false;

  for (const [key, jsType] of [
    ["code", "string"],
    ["errno", "number"],
    ["syscall", "string"],
  ] satisfies [keyof SystemError, JsType][]) {
    if (typeof (value as SystemError)[key] !== jsType) return false;
  }

  systemErrorMap ??= getSystemErrorMap();
  return systemErrorMap.has((value as SystemError).errno);
}

export function isSystemErrorWithCode<T extends string>(
  value: unknown,
  code: T,
): value is SystemError<T> {
  return isSystemError(value) && value.code === code;
}

// You can also define type guards for any specific system errors that you want to discriminate…
// https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/errors.html#common-system-errors

export function isConnectionRefusedError(
  value: unknown,
): value is SystemError<"ECONNREFUSED"> {
  return isSystemErrorWithCode(value, "ECONNREFUSED");
}

export function isNotFoundError(
  value: unknown,
): value is SystemError<"ENOENT"> {
  return isSystemErrorWithCode(value, "ENOENT");
}

// …etc.


You can use it in your code like this:
import { isConnectionRefusedError } from "./system_error"

function example() {
  try {
    // statements…
  } catch (cause) {
    if (isConnectionRefusedError(cause)) {
      cause
      //^? SystemError<"ECONNREFUSED">
      cause.code
      //    ^? BaseSystemError<"ECONNREFUSED">.code: "ECONNREFUSED"
    }
  }
}

// or the Redis example in your question:
redisClient.on("error", (err) => {
  if (isConnectionRefusedError(err)) {
    // It's a "connection refused" error; do something…
  } else {
    // do something different…
  }
});

Code in the TypeScript Playground

Pls try this to handle errors in Typescript:
interface NodeSystemError extends Error {
  code?: string;
  errno?: number;
  syscall?: string;
  path?: string;
  address?: string;
  port?: number;
}

redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
  const error = err as NodeSystemError;

  if (error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
    console.error('Connection refused:', error);
    throw new Error('Redis connection refused');
  } else if (error.code === 'EHOSTUNREACH') {
    console.error('Host unreachable:', error);
    throw new Error('Redis host unreachable');
  } else {
    console.error('Unhandled error:', error);
    throw error;
  }
});

we can also use instanceof
redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
  if (err instanceof Error && (err as any).code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
    console.error('Connection refused:', err);
    throw new Error('Redis connection refused');
  } else if (err instanceof Error && (err as any).code === 'EHOSTUNREACH') {
    console.error('Host unreachable:', err);
    throw new Error('Redis host unreachable');
  } else {
    console.error('Unhandled error:', err);
    throw err;
  }
});


Be careful when attempting to discriminate errors using instanceof in Node — the Node.js docs explain that using instanceof Error is not reliable for values originating in another realm: "A value being instanceof a native error class is not equivalent to isNativeError() returning true for that value. isNativeError() returns true for errors which come from a different realm while instanceof Error returns false for these errors"

Using as bypasses TypeScript's type checking, potentially leading to runtime errors.
